# How to auto create a Month calendar in google sheets. Where first day of the month start in the colum of the (name)day

Tags: google-sheets

I want to create a calendar like in the second image. But I can not figure out how to start the first column is a monday. So  I fill it by 'hand' like in the first image.

I tried to create it automatic. Starting with the first day of the month and add one day the next columns like in the second picture:

How I want it to look like:

[image: Picture1, how I want it]

How it is currently looking:

[image: Picture2, how I get it]

[Google sheets example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s4i4i-x8EQeelUFKfShcLnbUfR4oLGGPKR9S9m2ffug/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0):

I was solving the same problem for my bussiness, and I think I got the answer.

**Your first task is to determine the first "calendar monday" of the month.**

First, build the first day of the corresponding month:

```
[B2] =DATE(YEAR(A1); MONTH(A1); 1)
```

Then, get the WEEKDAY of the corresponding first day. The second argument represents what day your week starts with:

- If type is 1, days are counted from Sunday and the value of Sunday is 1, therefore the value of Saturday is 7.
- If type is 2, days are counted from Monday and the value of Monday is 1, therefore the value of Sunday is 7.
- If type is 3, days are counted from Monday and the value of Monday is 0, therefore the value of Sunday is 6.

In my case, we count the week starting from Monday. This means when the first day of the month lands on Monday, the return value will be 0.

```
[C2] =WEEKDAY(B2; 3)
```

The number you get represents how many days you need to substract from the initial date to get the first "calendar monday" of the month:

```
[D2] =B2 - C2
```

This date is what you are looking for. The final formula:

```
[A3] =DATE(YEAR(A1); MONTH(A1); 1) - WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1); MONTH(A1); 1); 3)
```

The rest of the days, simply add 1 to each preceding date.

```
[A4] =A3 + 1
[A5] =A4 + 1
```

And so on.

**Secondly, set the Number Format on the calendar cells to just show the day.**
Format -> Number -> More Formats -> More Date and Time Formats.
Select just the day from the drop down.

**Finally, use conditional formatting to "hide" the values that don't match the initial date**

Use a custom formula for the formatting, as follows:

```
=MONTH(A3) <> MONTH(A1)
```

Apply to the calendar range. This will format dates that **don't** belong to the current date, so make sure to paint that white.

And that's about it. Good luck!